# GORM で MySQL にデータを保存するときに Incorrect string value が出る原因を知りたい

Tags: mysql, go, docker, gorm

gormを使ってmysqlにデータを入れようとしています。

```
db, _ := gorm.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local")
file, err := os.Open("./db/seed.csv")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer file.Close()

reader := csv.NewReader(file)

var upon models.Upon
for {
    row, err := reader.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    upon = models.Upon{Name: row[0], Kana: row[1]}
    db.Create(&upon)
}
```

上記のコードを実行すると、`(Error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8F\x8A\xF0\x9F...' for column 'name' at row 1)`というエラーがでてしまいます。

```
mysql> show variables like 'character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table upons;
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                          |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| upons | CREATE TABLE `upons` (
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kana` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

mysqlの文字コードはutf8になっています。

上記のプログラムはdockerを使って実行しています。
mysqlのコンテナーに、golangのコンテナーからつないでいます。
両方とも公式のimageです。

ぜひご教授ください。

**追記**
のような絵文字でエラーが出ていました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「」のような絵文字はだいたい4バイト文字です。MySQL の utf8 は3バイト文字までしか扱えないので、utf8mb4 を指定する必要があります。
upons テーブルは utf8mb4 になっているので問題ないのですが、接続の charset が utf8 になっています。
1行目の gorm.Open の引数の charset=utf8 を charset=utf8mb4 にすればいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！